# ¿Cómo duplicar una columna de mi tabla SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente tabla Tbl_Info con una columna llamada Columna_1... quisiera duplicar esta columna que tenga exactamente la misma información y que se llame Columna_2... estoy usando HeidiSql como gestor de base de datos

Comment: Añade el codigo que tengas realizado

Comment: no tengo ningún codigo  amigo.. solo quiero duplicar una columna de mi base de datos.. y supongo que puedo hacerlo con SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer unicamente con sql, intependiente del gestor que uses

Modifica la tabla y crea la nueva columna

```
alter table Tbl_Info
add Columna_2 varchar(50) /*suponiendo que es varchar, copiala con el mismo tipo de dato*/
```

Copias los datos de la Columna_1 a la Columna_2 con un update

```
update Tbl_Info set Columna_2 = Columna_1
```

Ahora si quieres que cada ves que ingresen datos tendrias que actualizar **Columna_2** con los valores de **Columna_1**

Comment: amigo.... he podido crear la columna con el codigo que me diste.. pero al utilizar el update me sale el siguiente mensaje:

¿Ejecutar consultas insegurar sin clausula WHERE? Your query contains UPDATEs and/or DELETEs without a WHERE clause. Please confirm that you know what you're doing.

Comment: al darle a si pasa esto ... update tbl_perimetros set postventaatc_id = carteras_id;
/* Filas afectadas: 0  Filas encontradas: 0  Advertencias: 0  Duración para 1 consulta: 0,140 sec. */

Comment: si ese mensaje sale cuando vas actualizar toda una tabla, pero eso es lo que necesitamos, por lo tanto debes aceptar.

Comment: revisa que sean del mismo tipo, o añade este que es solo para "confundir" a la base: **where 1=1**

Comment: lo he hecho.. pero siguen viendose todas las filas como NULL

Comment: disculpa.. por estar haciendo pruebas habia eliminado informacion de la columna que estaba intentando duplicar... gracias me ha funcionado